Change the column name from Upper Case to LowerCase parquet file in pyspark
I want to convert a column name in the parquet file from Uppercase to Lowercase and rewrite it back at the same location (From EXE_TS to exe_ts). The parquet file is partitioned with a column named data_as_of_date.
I tried the below but it's not working. It's adding a column __index_level_0__:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Read the partitioned Parquet file into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.option("basePath", "/mnt/dataops/batchlogs/").parquet("/mnt/dataops/batchlogs")

# Rename the column
df = df.withColumnRenamed("EXE_TS", "exe_ts")

# Reset the index
df = df.toPandas().reset_index(drop=True)

# Convert the Pandas DataFrame back to a Spark DataFrame, dropping the index column
df = spark.createDataFrame(df).drop("__index_level_0__")

# Write the modified DataFrame back to the Parquet file, preserving the partitioning

df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("data_as_of_date").parquet("/mnt/dataops/batchlogs")


could we get some small samples of what the df.show() output looks like after the spark steps (e.g. withColumnRenamed, drop)

Why are you converting the df to pandas? I don't think it's needed if your only goal is to rename the column. You can skip that part and the rest of the code should work fine.
